# Get Date/Time Pattern in ICU4J

Tags: icu

I have a requirement where I need the pattern ICU uses to format the given date/time.

For example: If I have something like `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, en_US).format(currentDate)` gives me 5/3/2015, then I need an API which can tell me that the pattern ICU4J internally using is d/M/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out a solution, all you need to do is convert the DateFormat into a SimpleDateFormat and call toPattern().

((SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, en_US)).toPattern() returns d/M/y which is what I almost needed.